# Interactive password support for Ansible clone of Azure Repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, ansible, azure-repos

> **What specific syntax needs to be used to get Ansible to clone a git repository from Azure Repositories?**

The repository URL is `https://OrganizationName@dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/ProjectName/_git/RepositoryName` and we are able to clone it manually in an interactive shell by providing a requested password which we possess as follows:

```
$ git clone https://OrganizationName@dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/ProjectName/_git/RepositoryName  
Password for 'https://OrganizationName@dev.azure.com':
```

However, the Ansible example task that we have from the official Ansible documentation does not include any mention of a password, as follows:

```
- name: Clone a repo 
  git:
    repo: https://OrganizationName@dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/ProjectName/_git/RepositoryName
    dest: /src/RepositoryName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your password must be in your repo link as below

```
--- 
- name: Clone repo playbook
  hosts: dev

  vars_prompt: 
    - name: "git_user" 
      prompt: "Enter your git username" 
      private: no
    - name: "git_password" 
      prompt: "Password for 'https://OrganizationName@dev.azure.com'"
      private: yes 

  tasks:
  - name: Clone a repo 
    git:
      repo: https://{{ git_user | urlencode }}:{{ git_password | urlencode }}@dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/ProjectName/_git/RepositoryName
      dest: /src/RepositoryName
```

Comment: I just edited my answer I hope it could be useful for you.

Comment: When you use `vars_prompt` and execute your playbook, ansible ask you by both variables and you have to write them in your console. Other way could be add both variables in your `myVars.yaml` file and just add once the file in `vars_files` block. Try it and if you have some problems i'll help you gladly